# string representation of numeric literals in radices other than 2, 10, 16?

Tags: string, numbers, radix

C has the convention where `0x____` means a hexadecimal literal number, and I've seen `0b____` for binary literal number (most notably in [Java 7 Project Coin](http://java.dzone.com/articles/project-coin-examples-jdk-7)).

Is there anything out there for representing arbitrary radices? (up to base 36)

(e.g. `36rA0CZ` or `A0CZr36` with the 36r representing the radix and A0CZ representing the literal as expressed in that radix, in this case equal to the decimal number 467027)

I need to pick something for a program I'm working on, and would rather use an existing convention.

Comment: As another option that's not really worthy of being its own answer, A0CZ_36 is a close approximation of a subscript, which is a pretty common way to indicate the radix in textbooks and academic papers. That said, I'd think anyone comfortable with different radices would be comfortable with any of the options you and Jeremiah have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smalltalk uses the convention you show in your question (`radixrnumber`).  Zsh uses `radix#number`.  VHDL uses `radix#number#`.  Overall, the syntax you show is reasonable, and I do not believe there is a single notation that is standard or quasi-standard.

Comment: Algol68's radix of 2r0101, 4r0123123, 8r01234567 & 16r0ABCDEF &c. are orthogonal enough, whereas gcc's 0b010101, 01234567 and 0x0ABCD are a kind of random, esp. the  octal leading zero in "01234567" which is borderline dangerous.  Beside's the ternary 3r012012 may be useful for quantum computing. c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutrit

Answer (score 1):

add-on to Jeremiah Willcock's answer, from [Wikipedia's article on hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Representing_hexadecimal):

- Postscript uses *radix* `#` *number* (see [Postscript Reference Manual, 3rd Edition](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf), section 3.2.2)
- Ada uses *radix* `#` *number* `#`
- Algol-68 uses *radix* `r` *number*
- Common Lisp uses `#` *radix* `r` *number*

Of all of these, Postscript seems the most ubiquitous so I'll probably use that.